# How to check that a char is a period ('.') in c

Tags: c, char

So my program has to take in txt file that reads a grid of characters. Each character represents a certain command. A period (full stop) represents to keep doing the last command.

But when I compile my code `gcc -Wall -pedantic thebox.c -o thebox`, I get this warning:

> suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

This is the first part of the function that the warning refers to. The warning says line 78, which is the `if(command = ('.')` line -

```
int* getCommand(int next[2],char** gridArray)
{
        /* a function to return the command on the next position */
        int nextX = next[0];
        int nextY = next[1];
        char newCommand;
        char command = gridArray[nextX][nextY];
        if(command = ('.')) {
                newCommand = '1';
                gridArray[nextX][nextY] = newCommand;
        }
```

How do I fix this warning?

Comment: Use `command == '.'`.

Comment: omg, for all my other statements i had ==, i can't believe i didn't see that, thanks :)

Comment: Typo's should be banned ...... you didn't see because you didn't see it .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You check for equality with `==`.

A technique you can use to help avoid a similar problem in the future is to turn your comparison around:

```
        if('.' == command) {
```

If you forget the extra `=`, the compiler will complain. This technique doesn't always apply (like when you are comparing two variables), but it applies often enough that it can be worth the effort.

Comment: +1 for mention about reverse assignment syntax to avoid this issue (or easily spot the error if it occurs).

Answer (score 5):

To check for equality you use `==` not `=`, change that and you should be all set.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is correct, but there is a problem in the semantic. Everyone overlooks this. I've done it many times. 
`if(command == '.')`